# Is the an extension methods in .net Reactive extensions for Action<T>

Tags: action, system.reactive

I have two asynchronouse methods which take Action callbacks. I was wondering if there is an extension in Rx for actions?

My goal is to wait until both callback are called and then do some processing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from [Jesse and my upcoming book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430237473), but here you go, it's a freebie:

```
public Func<T1, IObservable<TRet>> FromCallbackPattern<T1, TRet>(Action<T1, Action<TRet>> originalMethod)
{
    return new Func<T1, IObservable<TRet>>((param1) => {
        var subject = new AsyncSubject<TRet>();

        try {
            return originalMethod(param1, (result) => {
                subject.OnNext(result);
                subject.OnCompleted();
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            subject.OnError(ex);
        }

        return subject;
    });
}
```

Here's how you use it:

```
// Here's a sample method that follows the callback pattern
public void DownloadPageTextAsync(string url, Action<string> callback);

var dlPageRx = FromCallbackPattern(DownloadPageTextAsync);

dlPageRx("http://www.jesseliberty.com")
    .Subscribe(pageText => Console.WriteLine(pageText));
```